# cannot see edittext in relativelayout (offscreen)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have the following relative layout that has a listview with an EditText underneath. I can't see the edittext as the list takes up the whole screen.

how can i show both the listview and the edittext on the screen at the same time without scrolling?

i've tried numerous layout params

thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewassessments"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:background="@color/blue_alpha_background"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Assessments" />

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/assessmentslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="#8fff"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="4px"
        android:layout_below="@id/textviewassessments" >
    </ListView>

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextassessments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="1"
        android:lines="7"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Please type any comments..."
        android:layout_below="@id/assessmentslist" >
        </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout and use weight.

Comment: hi, yes i suppose i could but i'm interseted why when i specify android:layout_below="@id/assessmentslist", the edittext does not show below the listview?

Comment: I think Listview Taking full height. so your EditText goes under neath it.

Comment: You could set fixed height to the listview and test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use RelativLayout then you should put one elment to the bottom and place the other above. Sample (not tested)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextassessments"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="1"
        android:lines="7"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="Please type any comments..."
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"   /> <!-- this will put the element on the bottom of the screen -->



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textviewassessments"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:background="@color/blue_alpha_background"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Assessments"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
  /> <!-- this will align the element to the head --> 

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/assessmentslist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="#8fff"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:divider="#FFCC00"
        android:dividerHeight="4px"
        android:layout_below="@id/textviewassessments"
        android:layout_above="@id/editTextassessments"
       /> <!-- this will put the the list between the both elements and stretch its size due match parent --> 


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `EditText` and align it to the bottom. Right now, you are telling it to be below the list so if the list takes up the full height then there is no room for it.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextassessments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="1"
    android:lines="7"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:hint="Please type any comments..."
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >  //here
</EditText>
```

If you want it to be below the list no matter what (even if the list doesn't fill the whole screen) then you may want to use [addFooterView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView(android.view.View))

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextassessments"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="1"
    android:lines="7"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:hint="Please type any comments..."
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
</EditText>
```

Comment: I have the same problem on Android 4.2.2 (API 17), and none of these suggestions worked. What i noticed is that if the page gets re-rendered (on orientation changed), the editText field eventually gets displayed. While investigating the problem I noticed that if i try to set programatically a text while the field is not visible, Android throws a stackoverflow error. Any idea what exactly is going on there?